# System level trigger on DML Command in plsql

Tags: plsql

Suppose there are n number of tables in the database. Whatever insert,update,delete happen across any table in the database, have to be captured in a table called "Audit_Trail", where we have the below columns in the audit trail tables.

Server_Name 
AT_date 
AT_time 
Table_name 
Column_name 
Action 
Old_value 
New_Value

The server on which table, on which column, on which date and time need to be captured. Also, the "Action" column tracks whether an action is an insert, update or delete and we have to capture the old value and new value as well.

So what is the best way to do this? Can we create a database level trigger which can fire trigger in case of any insert, update or delete?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use Oracle's own auditing functionality.

```
AUDIT ALL ON DEFAULT BY ACCESS;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG392

In response to comment ...

There is nothing unusual in wanting to audit every change made to tables in the database -- hence there is already functionality provided in the system for doing exactly that. It is better then using triggers because it cannot be bypassed as easily. However, if you want to use this pre-supplied, robust, simple to use functionality you might have to compromise on your specific requirements a little, but the payoff will be a superior solution that will use code and configuration in common with thousands of other Oracle systems.

Comment: Suppose there are n number of tables in the database. Whatever insert,update,delete happen across any table in the database, have to be captured in a table called "Audit_Trail", where we have the below columns in the audit trail tables. I want in this manner can i dont if i can get all the details into one seperate table Server_Name AT_date AT_time Table_name Column_name Action Old_value New_Value